Windhawk Ensure macro expansion is correct - Expected unqualified-id error
Errors from log
[{
    "resource": "/c:/ProgramData/Windhawk/EditorWorkspace/mod.wh.cpp",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "expected_unqualified_id",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Expected unqualified-id",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 23,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 23,
    "endColumn": 2
}]

c:\ProgramData\Windhawk\EditorWorkspace\mod.wh.cpp:24:3: error: expected unqualified-id
   24 |   "closeButtonHoverColor": {
      |   ^
c:\ProgramData\Windhawk\EditorWorkspace\mod.wh.cpp:81:16: error: expected ')'
   81 |         Wh_Log(buffer);  // Ensure macro expansion is correct
      |                ^
c:\ProgramData\Windhawk\EditorWorkspace\mod.wh.cpp:81:9: note: to match this '('
   81 |         Wh_Log(buffer);  // Ensure macro expansion is correct
      |         ^
c:/Program Files/Windhawk/Compiler/include/windhawk_api.h:71:35: note: expanded from macro 'Wh_Log'
   71 |             InternalWh_Log_Wrapper(L"[%d:%S]: " message, __LINE__, \
      |                                   ^
2 errors generated.

Full mode code
// ==WindhawkMod==
// @id              close-button-hover-color-changer
// @name            Close Button Hover Color Changer
// @description     Changes the close button's hover color across all applications
// @version         1.0
// @author          AssistantModder
// @github          https://github.com/AssistantModder
// @include         *
// @compilerOptions -ldwmapi -luser32 -lgdi32
// ==/WindhawkMod==

// ==WindhawkModReadme==
/*
This mod customizes the close button's hover color across all applications that use the Windows DWM API.
Features:
- Change the hover color of the close button.
- Basic error handling and logging for troubleshooting.
*/
// ==/WindhawkModReadme==

// Define Windhawk Mod Settings
// ==WindhawkModSettings==
{
  "closeButtonHoverColor": {
    "type": "string",
    "default": "#FF6666",
    "title": "Hover Color",
    "description": "Color when hovering over the close button."
  },
  "enableMod": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "default": true,
    "title": "Mod Enabled",
    "description": "Toggle the mod on or off."
  },
  "logLevel": {
    "type": "integer",
    "default": 1,
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 4,
    "title": "Logging Level",
    "description": "Set logging level: 0-None, 1-Error, 2-Warning, 3-Info, 4-Debug"
  }
}
// ==/WindhawkModSettings==

#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <windhawk_utils.h>

// Structure to hold the mod's settings
struct ModSettings {
    COLORREF hoverColor;
    BOOL enableMod;
    int logLevel;
} settings;

// Function prototype for the DWM API call
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *DwmSetWindowAttributeFptr)(HWND, DWORD, LPCVOID, DWORD);

// Original function pointer
DwmSetWindowAttributeFptr OriginalDwmSetWindowAttribute = nullptr;

// Converts a hex string to COLORREF
COLORREF HexStringToCOLORREF(const wchar_t* hexColor) {
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    if (wcslen(hexColor) == 7 && swscanf_s(hexColor, L"#%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) == 3) {
        return RGB(r, g, b);
    }
    Wh_Log(L"Error: Invalid hex color format '%s'. Using default red.", hexColor);
    return RGB(255, 0, 0); // Default to red on failure
}

// Custom logging function based on the log level
void CustomLog(int level, const wchar_t* format, ...) {
    if (level <= settings.logLevel) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        wchar_t buffer[256];
        vswprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]), format, args);
        Wh_Log(buffer);  // Ensure macro expansion is correct
        va_end(args);
    }
}

// Hook function for DwmSetWindowAttribute to change close button hover color
HRESULT WINAPI HookDwmSetWindowAttribute(HWND hwnd, DWORD dwAttribute, LPCVOID pvAttribute, DWORD cbAttribute) {
    if (settings.enableMod && dwAttribute == 35) { // 35 is the undocumented DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR_HOVER
        *(COLORREF*)pvAttribute = settings.hoverColor;
        CustomLog(4, L"Set hover caption color to 0x%06X", settings.hoverColor);
    }
    return OriginalDwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, dwAttribute, pvAttribute, cbAttribute);
}

// Load settings from the Windhawk mod settings
void LoadSettings() {
    settings.hoverColor = HexStringToCOLORREF(Wh_GetStringSetting(L"closeButtonHoverColor"));
    settings.enableMod = Wh_GetIntSetting(L"enableMod") != 0;  // Interpret as boolean
    settings.logLevel = Wh_GetIntSetting(L"logLevel");
}

// Initialization function for the mod
BOOL Wh_ModInit() {
    LoadSettings();

    HMODULE dwmapiModule = GetModuleHandle(L"dwmapi.dll");
    if (!dwmapiModule) {
        CustomLog(1, L"Failed to get dwmapi.dll module handle");
        return FALSE;
    }

    OriginalDwmSetWindowAttribute = (DwmSetWindowAttributeFptr)GetProcAddress(dwmapiModule, "DwmSetWindowAttribute");
    if (!OriginalDwmSetWindowAttribute) {
        CustomLog(1, L"Failed to get DwmSetWindowAttribute function address");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Hook the DwmSetWindowAttribute function
    Wh_SetFunctionHook((void*)OriginalDwmSetWindowAttribute, (void*)HookDwmSetWindowAttribute, (void**)&OriginalDwmSetWindowAttribute);
    CustomLog(3, L"Mod initialized successfully");
    return TRUE;
}

// Function called when the mod settings are changed
void Wh_ModSettingsChanged() {
    LoadSettings();
    CustomLog(3, L"Settings reloaded");
}

// Uninitialization function for the mod
void Wh_ModUninit() {
    CustomLog(3, L"Mod uninitialized");
}

Summary of Fixes Attempted So Far
Corrected Comment Placement:

Moved the Windhawk mod settings outside of comment blocks.
Fixed errors where mod settings were not properly defined outside comment blocks.
Adjusted Logging Macro:

Ensured correct usage of Wh_Log macro.
Verified the logging function handles format strings properly using vswprintf_s.
Fixed Use of Reserved Keywords:

Avoided using reserved keywords like char for variable names.
Corrected Function Pointer Handling:

Ensured function pointers for DwmSetWindowAttribute are correctly defined and used.
Error Handling in HexStringToCOLORREF:

Added error handling for invalid hex color format.
Boolean Settings Retrieval:

Used Wh_GetBoolSetting for retrieving boolean settings.


Based on the decoration to the code, I expect there's some tool that processes this file, generates a proper C++ file, and then compiles the generated file.

One way to establish that your code should be correct might be to link to Windhawk documentation and explain how your code adheres to that documentation. When using a library for which StackOverflow has no tag, it is up to the asker to provide all necessary information about that library; the library's documentation is often sufficient.

Seems the code in question is a mod file intended to be processed by this project: https://github.com/ramensoftware/windhawk, and here's the doc for it: https://github.com/ramensoftware/windhawk/wiki The file is not supposed to be compiled as-is by a C++ compiler, it is supposed to be pre-processed by this project first, and then it invokes clang to compile what's left over.

fixed issue thanks for help
